# How do I add this to an arraylist within a static method?

Tags: java, methods, static, arraylist

I'm learning the ropes with Java and I've hit a snag with ArrayLists. The gist of my program is to take some user input parameters, create a class Foo with those parameters, and then add it to an arraylist. The problem is, it complains that I can't reference a non-static type from a static method. The only examples I can find online deal with adding constants ("Cat", "5.0" etc) to arraylists which doesn't really help me.

I put the gist of my code below. I've moved the arraylist off to its own class Bar and added an add method which just does arraylist.add(foo), if only as a crapshoot to make it work (it doesn't). I omitted the loop but it loops a number of times after the definitions, so the arraylist gets populated.

```
public class MainClass{

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a, b;

a = scanner.nextint();
b = scanner.nextint();

Foo foo = new Foo(a, b);
Bar.add(foo); //Complains here
}
}
```

Edit: Here is Bar explicitly

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Bar{
private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

public void add(Foo foo){
    list.add(foo);
}
}
```

If it helps, the object foo isn't changed after creation.

How do I get around this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why doesn't you show ALL the code that isn't working

Comment: yeah, your *gist* is missing a declaration of Bar, and/or the error, so it isn't a very good *gist*

Comment: edited; the error is pretty much as I said; "non-static method add(java.lang.Object) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: if your list only contains one type of object, you should look into using generics, too, and declare that as `private List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();`

Comment: This illustrates why you should always quote error messages exactly. You originally said "it complains that I can't reference a non-static type from a static method" but then you said the error was "non-static method add(java.lang.Object) cannot be referenced from a static context". There is a difference between a non-static type and a non-static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without information about Bar, or the actual error it complains about, we can't help much.

I'd presume its because the `Bar.add` method isn't static, or `Bar` isn't static.

```
// a class with a public static method that encapsulates a static list
public class Bar
{
    static List<Foo> innerlist = new ArrayList<Foo>();

    public static void add( Foo o )
    {
        innerList.add(o);
    }
}
```

or do you intend "Bar" to be a static list member of something else?

```
// a class with a static member
public class OtherClass
{
     public static List<Foo> Bar = new ArrayList<Foo>();
}
```

then your code would need a `OtherClass.Bar.add(o)` instead of just Bar.add(o);

Comment: Here is Bar; you're right, it's not static. public class Bar{ private Arraylist list = new Arraylist(); public void add(Object O){ this.add(O);}}

Comment: you either need to create an instance of `Bar`, and use that in your main method, or you need to declare the `add` method to be static on your bar class, and make that `list` static too.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

option 1: create an instance of Bar and add foo to that instance. This is my preferred option

```
Bar b=new Bar();
b.add(foo);
```

option 2: make your add(...) method static. this also means your "list" should also be static. both are bad.

Comment: I might try this too. Thank you.